# If atomic orbitals are orthogonal, how can one mix then in Molecular Orbital Theory?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory

If two molecular orbitals are orthogonal, their net overlap is 0. Which means that the mixture of them would result in no observable change in any of the orbitals if they occur. However, this contrasts totally with the Molecular Orbital Theory as well as the Valence Bond Theory, whereby atomic orbitals are often combined.
In this manner, is it not plausible that the orthogonality condition of the wave function hinders the combination of orthogonal wave functions -i.e. atomic orbitals?

Comment: Atomic orbitals ***of one atom*** are orthogonal, but those of different atoms aren't.

Comment: This makes sense to explaining chemical bonds, but not to explaining hybridization in an atom.

Comment: In MO theory, you first mix orbitals to fit them to the symmetry of the molecule. That in itself does not explain bonding, but it prepares you for then combining the symmetry-adapted combinations of one set of atoms (e.g. the hydrogen atoms of methane) with the symmetry matched of another set of atoms (e.g. the carbon atom of methane).

Comment: Within MO theory, there (strictly speaking) is no hybridisation. For a single atom such a description (without an external potential) doesn't make much sense. And in VB theory there are (strictly speaking) no eigenvalues of the hybrid orbitals. A VB description of a single atom also doesn't make much sense; the theory is not designed for this. You also cannot just mix and match both approaches.

Comment: @Karsten thus, in MO Theory, I first mix the present orbitais from the atoms to find if the orbitals can make one MO - with aid of Group Theory - for then populating the MO according to the Aufbau Principle, which in turn enable me to analyse the degree of bonding in the molecule?

Comment: @Martin-マーチン and what is the implication of having no eigenvalues for the orbitals? That we cannot analyse quantitatively the bond lengths or angles, since there is no wave functions whatosever or orbitals being precisely described?

Comment: There is of course a wave function as the total description is in VB theory the same as in MO theory. Just the parts towards this equivalence can't be interchanged. And conclusions from one theory don't carry over to the other. There are a few questions on the platform. It's not a simple topic, and certainly nothing for the comment section. Here is something to get you started: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/109615/4945

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bond is formed between *two* atoms, and a pair of AOs from each doesn't share the same  coordinate system. Obviously, because there is a finite distance, the bond lenght, between the (0,0,0) coordinates of each AO.

That means the concept of orthogonality makes no sense for the constituent AOs of a MO. Simply speaking you can freely align the two coordinate systems to give the biggest overlap. Which is what nature does, because that gives the biggest energy gain from the bond.

Comment: Thanks to you and the other guys' clarifications, it was clear to me that I was mixing Quantum Mechanics theories with VB theory, which is not applicable.